# Is there an equivalent to Vite's build.outDir in SvelteKit, and how can you use it?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to adapt to SvelteKit the Django-Svelte setup from [this page](https://dev.to/besil/my-django-svelte-setup-for-fullstack-development-3an8) where, using Rollup, the Svelte App is build inside the static directory of the Django app.

I cannot find how this can be done. I assume it has to do with Kit's options like paths.base, paths.assets and appDir but I cannot even configure paths.assets in any way.

In Vite, there is build.outDir but it is ignored by Vite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SvelteKit, the output is usually based around the adapter. For example, the [adapter-static](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static#usage) allows to change where the output is placed. All the output is based off the `.sveltekit` folder, which I do not believe is configurable.

Comment: Thank you. I'll stick to rollup as in the tutorial, then.